# Проблема с программой проверки является ли заданная квадратная матрица магическим квадратом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сразу скажу нету никаких ошибок компиляции или чего то подобного

Есть задача:

> Магическим квадратом порядка N называется квадратная матрица размера N
>   × N , составленная из чисел 1, 2, ..., N 2 так, что суммы по каждому
>   столбцу, каждой строке и каждой из двух больших диагоналей равны между
>   собой. Напишите программу, которая проверяет, является ли заданная
>   квадратная матрица магическим квадратом.
>
> **Входные данные**:
>
> В первой строке вводится размер матрицы N . В следующих
>   N строках вводятся строки матрицы, по N значений в каждой, разделённые
>   пробелами.
>
> **Выходные данные**:
>
> Программа должна вывести слово 'YES', если матрица
>   является магическим квадратом, и слово 'NO', если не является.

Есть моё решение:

```
n = int(input())
mtr = []
for i in range(n):
  mtr.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
last = sum(mtr[0])
f = True

for i in range(1, n):
  if sum(mtr[i]) != last:
    f = False
  last = sum(mtr[i])

for j in range(n):
  sm = 0
  for i in range(n):
    sm += mtr[i][j]
  if sm != last:
    f = False
  last = sm

sm = 0
for i in range(n):
  sm += mtr[i][i]
if sm != last:
  f = False
last = sm

sm = 0
for i in range(n):
  sm += mtr[n - i - 1][i]
if sm != last:
  f = False

if f:
  print("YES")
else:
  print("NO")
```

Проверяющая система говорит, что это неправильное решение - Вердикт 17/19 правильных ответов

Можете помочь с решением?

Comment: К сожалению, в условии достаточно расплывчато описан формат входных данных. Вы нигде не проверяете, что в матрице находятся именно числа от 1 до N^2. Возможно, это на самом деле не гарантируется.

Answer (score 2):

Вы забыли проверить это условие!

> квадратная матрица размера N × N , составленная из чисел 1, 2, ..., N^2

Кроме того, отрефакторьте ваш код:

1. Не нужно продолжать проверку дальше, если вы уже нашли, что `f = False`. Для этого вынесите проверку в отдельную функцию и делайте `return False`, тогда код дальше выполняться не будет.
2. Ззачем каждый раз переприсваивать `last`, если это должно быть одно и то же значение? Просто запомните его один раз в самом начале, и больше не изменяйте.
3. Всю эту процедурщину можно заменить list comprehension, будет гораздо короче и красивее. Например, проверка главной диагонали: `if sum(mtr[i][i] for i in range(n)) != last: return False`. Остальное сделайте сами.

Answer (score 0):

> Магическим квадратом порядка N называется квадратная матрица размера N × N , составленная из чисел 1, 2, ..., N 2 так, что суммы по каждому столбцу, каждой строке и каждой из двух больших диагоналей равны между собой.

Можно все условия подряд проверить:

- матрица квадратная NxN по определению входных данных
- на входе не написано, что значения в матрице обязаны быть числами -- проверяем при чтении:

```
N = int(input())  # it is guaranteed to be integer
try:
    matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(N)]
except ValueError:  # non integer
    print('NO')
else:
    print('YES' if N == 0 or is_magic_square(matrix, sum(matrix[0]), N) else 'NO')
```

где `is_magic_square()` проверяет:

- суммы в каждой строке совпадают
- суммы в каждом столбце совпадают
- сумма по главной диагонали совпадает
- сумма по побочной диагонали
- набор чисел в матрице совпадает с диапазоном 1..N<sup>2</sup>

```
def is_magic_square(matrix, S, N):
    return (all(sum(row) == S for row in matrix)
            and all(sum(column) == S for column in zip(*matrix))
            and sum(matrix[i][i] for i in range(N)) == S
            and sum(matrix[i][N-1-i] for i in range(N)) == S
            and set(x for row in matrix for x in row) == set(range(1, N**2 + 1)))
```

Пример:

```
>>> is_magic_square([[2, 7, 6],
...                  [9, 5, 1],
...                  [4, 3, 8]], 15, 3)
True
```